How can click on the print icon using selenium python?
I am trying to click on the print icon if pdf open in chrome browser but I am unable to click on the print icon, see the below screenshot Can any one help on this.

Code:-
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



def main(PDF_URL):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.get(PDF_URL)
    browser.implicitly_wait(180)
    print("browser open successfully..")
    time.sleep(5)
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
    # print(soup)
    print_button = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'toolbar').find_element(By.XPATH, "//cr-icon-button//div[@id='icon']/iron-icon")
    print_button.click()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PDF_URL = "D:/Sandeep/ATP_Project/Web-Scraping/pdf_save/pdf/10.1055-s-2001-17364.pdf"
    main(PDF_URL)


In this case, you don't have to click that print button, you can just use Ctrl+P for printing the page.
You can see this page for your desired answer How to send Ctrl+P in selenium

Thanks for sharing the input browser.execute_script('window.print();') is working for me but  webdriver.ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('P').key_up     (Keys.CONTROL).perform() is not working. Do you have any idea for this?

Someone suggested to use pyautoit library. so use pip install pyautoit for installation then use import autoit autoit.send("^p") to send Ctrl+P in the page.

On SO you are required to put the answer to the question in THIS answer, not just link to another answer.
